# Eclipse Console Command Goto line - inverse search

Tags: eclipse, parameters, line, goto, inverse

Is there any way to make Eclipse jump to a specific line out of the console?

e.g.

```
/usr/bin/eclipse --file=/foo/bar --line=3456
```

Without opening a new instance of Eclipse if one is already open.

Specifically, I am using TeXlipse to create PDF files. In my PDF viewer, I can get the TeX line I have currently selected and execute console commands with it in order to navigate my TeX-Editor (Eclipse) to that line.

Related [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305336).